# PHP and Wordpress on GAE, How to update? missing zlib ext

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have installed and gotten the example working for Wordpress on GAE as described here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project
Which puts PHP in:

```
--php_executable_path=~/php-5.4.25/installdir/bin/php-cgi
```

so my local start up command looks like:

```
tom@tom-sam:~$ dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=~/php-5.4.25/installdir/bin/php-cgi ~/Documents/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project_build
```

So I am using the default GAE PHP version, I can run my project locally and on GAE
In order to update the install, both to upgrade to WP 4.0 and update Plug-ins.. I want to take advantage of the WP auto update mechanisms but when I try I get

```
Abort class-pclzip.php : Missing zlib extensions
```

After the update downloads.. 
I'd prefer to update the GAE version of PHP if possible?
or install and run PHP from a stock APT get for Ubuntu, Since I've never worked with PHP.. not sure how to best go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it's probably OK to just apt-get the stock PHP so you can update your WordPress install locally before pushing the updated version to production.

Comment: for the record I installed the PHP5 meta package, the php5-cgi package and the php5-mysql package from the Ubuntu repos I was then able to execute   tom@tom-sam:~$ dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi ~/Documents/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project note the new executable path... The upgrade to 4.0 proceeded without a hitch.. I'll just have to see how the GAE deploy goes...